# How to insert a banner image in a random listview row ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, listview, rows, banner

How can I insert a banner image in a listview at a random row without affecting the other data rows in ASP.NET 4

Answer (score 1):

This will get a random number for you:

```
Random random = new Random();

int maxValue = (number of rows in your Data Source);

int r = random.Next(maxValue);
```

Then in the ListView.ItemDataBound event, when the index = maxValue - 1, display the picture.

Comment: Thanks, but the rows have bound fields, in the image row I want only the image. How can I hide those bound columns in the image row?

Comment: is the image like an ad randomly placed in a grid of results?